# Reference BLAS/LAPACK from NETLIB is twice as fast as MKL for complex numbers

Tags: petsc, performance, blas, complex-arithmetic, intel-mkl

I'm solving the [Helmholtz equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) using PETSc.  I found with the PETSc configure option `--download-f-blas-lapack` my program runs twice as fast over running it with MKL. Is this a common trend or are there other factors at play? I'm using gcc and Open MPI with PETSc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is usually caused by trying to use a threaded MKL combined with MPI, resulting in over-subscription.  Either explicitly configure PETSc to use non-threaded MKL or add [`MKL_NUM_THREADS=1`](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/mkl/lin/MKL_UG_managing_performance/Using_Additional_Threading_Control.htm) to your environment.